# Angular 4 Call HttpResponse inside the component

Tags: angular, typescript, httpresponse

I'm trying to get the response from my Post with angular 4. This is my code:

> app.component.html:

```
`findAccordiSmall(pagination: Pagination) {
        this.accordiListTableLoading = true;
        debugger;
        this.accordiService.findAccordiSmall(pagination).subscribe(
          (res: HttpResponse<any>) => {
            res.headers.get('offset');
            res.headers.get('count');

            this.agreementList= res.body;

          }      errors => {
        this.accordiListTableLoading = false;
        Utils.notifyErrors(errors, this.notificationsService);
      }
    );
```

> Service.ts

```
findAccordiSmall(pagination: Pagination): Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {

    const queryParams = this.getHttpParams(pagination).toString();

    return this.http.post(`${this.ENDPOINT}/agreements-paginated?${queryParams}`,pagination, { observe: 'response' })
        .catch(error => Utils.handleError(error, this.router, 'Errore nel recupero delle pratiche'));
}
```

The POST is sending me every data I want (headers, response etc) but I just cant use those values inside my components. How can I call them?
I have to fill:
    `agreementList: Agreement[];`  with the response.

Sorry for the confusion, if you need something more just tell me.

EDIT:[This is my response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkFwi.png)

Edit2:

> Component.ts

```
  findAccordiSmall(pagination: Pagination) {
    this.accordiListTableLoading = true;
    this.accordiService.findAccordiSmall(pagination).subscribe(
      (res: Agreement[]) => {
        this.agreementList= res;
      },
  errors => {
    this.accordiListTableLoading = false;
    Utils.notifyErrors(errors, this.notificationsService);
  }
);
```

> service.ts

```
 findAccordiSmall(pagination: Pagination): Observable<Agreement[]> {

        const queryParams = this.getHttpParams(pagination).toString();
        debugger;
        return this.http.post<Agreement[]>(`${this.ENDPOINT}/agreements-paginated?${queryParams}`,pagination, { observe: 'response' })
            .map(res => res)
            .catch(error => Utils.handleError(error, this.router, 'Errore nel recupero delle pratiche'));}
```

Comment: r u using HttpClient or Http?

Comment: Can you show what response are you receiving?

Comment: Im using HttpClient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to fill `agreementList: Agreement[]` with response, all you need to do is assign `res` (value returned by a service function) to it. No need to use `res.body`.
You have `this.agreementList= res.body;`. This is wrong.
This line should read `this.agreementList = res;`

EDIT: Updated component code:

```
findAccordiSmall(pagination: Pagination) {
    this.accordiListTableLoading = true;
    debugger;
    this.accordiService.findAccordiSmall(pagination).subscribe(
      (res: Agreement[]) => {
        this.accordiListTableLoading = false;
        this.agreementList= res;
      },
  errors => {
    this.accordiListTableLoading = false;
    Utils.notifyErrors(errors, this.notificationsService);
  }
);
```

I updated your service function with correct return value, you also need to `map` over it.

```
findAccordiSmall(pagination: Pagination): Observable<Agreement[]> {

const queryParams = this.getHttpParams(pagination).toString();

return this.http.post<Agreement[]>(`${this.ENDPOINT}/agreements-paginated?${queryParams}`,pagination, { observe: 'response' })
    .map(res => res)
    .catch(error => Utils.handleError(error, this.router, 'Errore nel recupero delle pratiche'));
```

}

So now it returns `Observable<Agreement[]>`, meaning that when you subscribe to it, `res` inside subscribe will be unwrapped from an `Observable, and it's type will be`Agreement[]`

`subscribe((res: Agreement[]) => {})`

Comment: if I use this.agreementList = res; there is an error: "the type HttpResponse<any> is not assignable to type Agreement[], In type HttpResponse<any> is missing the property 'length'.

Comment: In that case this line `(res: HttpResponse<any>) => {` should read
`(res: HttpResponse<Agreement[]>) => {` and all will be good.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but i still have the same error :)

Comment: Of course - my mistake, res is no longer wrapped in `HttpResponse`. So the line should read `(res: Agreement[]) => {` 
I updated my answer with full component code.

Comment: Thank you again for your help, when i go in debug mode i can see that "res" in not defined... :I   oh and you can remove the res.headers since i dont need them

Comment: Yes, the res is undefined, because in your service, you should be mapping over it. See the updated service function and run it again. I am brain farting on your code, I should see the missing pieces before.

Comment: Im really sorry but its still not defined, i feel so stupid now... its my first project in angular and i cant even do a post eheh

Comment: Don't worry, I would be doing silly mistakes in React or Vue if I started up. Ok, in that case replace `.map(res => res)`in service with `.map(res => { console.log('%c res', 'color: green', res); return res; }` and inspect the value of res in the map function. If it's defined and map returns it, it should be defined inside `subscribe` function in the component. You are definitely using `HttpClient`, right?

Comment: The type Observable<HttpResponse<Object>> not assignable to type Observable<Agreement[]>.   Yes im using (private http: HttpClient).

Comment: Ok, we are getting closer here. We need to convert HttpResponse Observable to Observable of Agreement[]. Since Angular 4.3, this can be done easily. Update this code `return this.http.post` to `return this.http.post<Agreement[]>` in the service.

Comment: eh not working again. Same error as before Edit: i was wrong ive miss typed :))

Comment: Ok, at this stage I need you to paste the whole of your code - the last version - update your question with the latest and I will see where seems to be the problem.

Comment: First res = message: "Unexpected end of input"
Second res = message: "illegal return statement"


Post edited again

Comment: Remove the `debugger;` It stops the code in a place where you can't inspect what is the value of `res` - that's why you see the above error messages. Then run the code.

Comment: Also, this line `this.accordiListTableLoading = false;` should be above `this.agreementList= res;` so you hide the loader when data arrives.

Comment: I cant use the res with console.log that you posted since its giving me a lot of formatting errors. If i just use res=> res  in  this.agreementList= res; is sending me a 200 OK. so i think its working

Comment: well then drop `console.log(res)`; under these two lines in your component to see you get res inside the component `this.accordiListTableLoading = false;
        this.agreementList= res;` and you should be good.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! everything is working now!  im in debt with you :)